# Mongodb: How to get a list of subcollection

Tags: mongodb

I have a member collection with following data:

```
db.member.insert(
{
    userName: "TanNM",
    password: "xxx",
    wantList: [{
        title: "Want 1.1 - HN",
        description: "Want 1.1 description",
        province:{
            name: "Ha Noi",
            districtList:[ { name: "Ha Dong", qty: 25 }, { name: "Ba Dinh", qty: 50 } , { name: "Cau Giay", qty: 25 }, { name: "Hoan Kiem", qty: 50 } ]
        }
    }, {
        title: "Want 1.2 - HN",
        description: "Want 1.2 description",
        province:{
            name: "SG",
            districtList:[ { name: "Ha Dong", qty: 25 }, { name: "Ba Dinh", qty: 50 } , { name: "Cau Giay", qty: 25 }, { name: "Hoan Kiem", qty: 50 } ]
        }
    }],
    stock: [ { size: "S", qty: 25 }, { size: "M", qty: 50 } ],
    category: "clothing"
})

db.member.insert(
{
    userName: "MinhNN",
    password: "xxx",
    wantList: [{
        title: "Want 2.1 - HN",
        description: "Want 2.1 description",
        province:{
            name: "Ha Noi",
            districtList:[ { name: "Ha Dong", qty: 25 }, { name: "Ba Dinh", qty: 50 } , { name: "Cau Giay", qty: 25 }, { name: "Hoan Kiem", qty: 50 } ]
        }
    }, {title: "Want 2.2 - HN",
        description: "Want 2.2 description",
        province:{
            name: "Ha Noi",
            districtList:[ { name: "Ha Dong", qty: 25 }, { name: "Ba Dinh", qty: 50 } , { name: "Cau Giay", qty: 25 }, { name: "Hoan Kiem", qty: 50 } ]
        }
    }],
    stock: [ { size: "S", qty: 25 }, { size: "M", qty: 50 } ],
    category: "clothing"
})

db.member.insert(
{
    userName: "DungNP",
    password: "xxx",
    wantList: {
        title: "Want 3 - SG",
        description: "Want 3 description",
        province:{
            name: "TP Ho Chi Minh",
            districtList:[ { name: "Ha Dong", qty: 25 }, { name: "Ba Dinh", qty: 50 } , { name: "Cau Giay", qty: 25 }, { name: "Hoan Kiem", qty: 50 } ]
        }
    },
    stock: [ { size: "S", qty: 25 }, { size: "M", qty: 50 } ],
    category: "clothing"
})
```

Member have some Want (wantList), Want in a province/district.

How to get all "want" (Not all document) of all member with `province.name` is "Ha Noi"

Comment: Hi! I've deleted my answer as it doesn't solve your issue. I finally got you mean, which is a bit tricky for me at the moment. When I have time I will try to dig a bit on this, but I hope someone will answer your question. :) Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! @oscar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer you are looking for is this

```
db.member.find({"wantList.province.name": "Ha Noi"});
```

If you only need to output the "wantList", you should try this query

```
db.member.find({"wantList.province.name": "Ha Noi"}, {"wantList": 1});
```

This will only output the "wantList" array where one of the provinces equals "Ha Noi". I hope this was the answer you were looking for.

The second query returns the following:

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("56568bbd2688b376a56878c5"), "wantList" : [ { "title" : "Want 1.1 - HN", "description" : "Want 1.1 description", "province" : { "name" : "Ha Noi", "districtList" : [ { "name" : "Ha Dong", "qty" : 25 }, { "name" : "Ba Dinh", "qty" : 50 }, { "name" : "Cau Giay", "qty" : 25 }, { "name" : "Hoan Kiem", "qty" : 50 } ] } }, { "title" : "Want 1.2 - HN", "description" : "Want 1.2 description", "province" : { "name" : "SG", "districtList" : [ { "name" : "Ha Dong", "qty" : 25 }, { "name" : "Ba Dinh", "qty" : 50 }, { "name" : "Cau Giay", "qty" : 25 }, { "name" : "Hoan Kiem", "qty" : 50 } ] } } ] }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("56568bc72688b376a56878c6"), "wantList" : [ { "title" : "Want 2.1 - HN", "description" : "Want 2.1 description", "province" : { "name" : "Ha Noi", "districtList" : [ { "name" : "Ha Dong", "qty" : 25 }, { "name" : "Ba Dinh", "qty" : 50 }, { "name" : "Cau Giay", "qty" : 25 }, { "name" : "Hoan Kiem", "qty" : 50 } ] } }, { "title" : "Want 2.2 - HN", "description" : "Want 2.2 description", "province" : { "name" : "Ha Noi", "districtList" : [ { "name" : "Ha Dong", "qty" : 25 }, { "name" : "Ba Dinh", "qty" : 50 }, { "name" : "Cau Giay", "qty" : 25 }, { "name" : "Hoan Kiem", "qty" : 50 } ] } } ] }
```

EDIT:

I think you are looking for this answer:

```
db.member.find(
  {"wantList.province.name": "Ha Noi"}, 
  {"wantList": {"$elemMatch": {"province.name": "Ha Noi"}}}
);
```

Which returns:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56568bbd2688b376a56878c5"), "wantList" : [ { "title" : "Want 1.1 - HN", "description" : "Want 1.1 description", "province" : { "name" : "Ha Noi", "districtList" : [ { "name" : "Ha Dong", "qty" : 25 }, { "name" : "Ba Dinh", "qty" : 50 }, { "name" : "Cau Giay", "qty" : 25 }, { "name" : "Hoan Kiem", "qty" : 50 } ] } } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56568bc72688b376a56878c6"), "wantList" : [ { "title" : "Want 2.1 - HN", "description" : "Want 2.1 description", "province" : { "name" : "Ha Noi", "districtList" : [ { "name" : "Ha Dong", "qty" : 25 }, { "name" : "Ba Dinh", "qty" : 50 }, { "name" : "Cau Giay", "qty" : 25 }, { "name" : "Hoan Kiem", "qty" : 50 } ] } } ] }
```

If you want to remove the _id you just input the following query:

```
db.member.find(
  {"wantList.province.name": "Ha Noi"}, 
  {"wantList": {"$elemMatch": {"province.name": "Ha Noi"}}, "_id": 0}
);
```

EDIT 2:

I think aggregation is needed to solve your problem. Try this query.

```
db.member.aggregate([
  {"$match": {"wantList.province.name": "Ha Noi"}}, 
  {"$unwind": "$wantList"}, 
  {"$match": {"wantList.province.name": "Ha Noi"}}, 
  {"$project": {"_id": 0, "wantList": 1}}
]);
```

Which returns:

```
{ "wantList" : { "title" : "Want 1.1 - HN", "description" : "Want 1.1 description", "province" : { "name" : "Ha Noi", "districtList" : [ { "name" : "Ha Dong", "qty" : 25 }, { "name" : "Ba Dinh", "qty" : 50 }, { "name" : "Cau Giay", "qty" : 25 }, { "name" : "Hoan Kiem", "qty" : 50 } ] } } }
{ "wantList" : { "title" : "Want 2.1 - HN", "description" : "Want 2.1 description", "province" : { "name" : "Ha Noi", "districtList" : [ { "name" : "Ha Dong", "qty" : 25 }, { "name" : "Ba Dinh", "qty" : 50 }, { "name" : "Cau Giay", "qty" : 25 }, { "name" : "Hoan Kiem", "qty" : 50 } ] } } }

{ "wantList" : { "title" : "Want 2.2 - HN", "description" : "Want 2.2 description", "province" : { "name" : "Ha Noi", "districtList" : [ { "name" : "Ha Dong", "qty" : 25 }, { "name" : "Ba Dinh", "qty" : 50 }, { "name" : "Cau Giay", "qty" : 25 }, { "name" : "Hoan Kiem", "qty" : 50 } ] } } }
```

I think this is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: No I have checked its not answering question, Have you verified result?

Comment: Why is it not the answer. The last query only returns the wantList where the province name is Ha Noi. Could you specify why this isn't the right answer?

Comment: I might be wrong sorry, but will you please add result of that query in answer.

Comment: Just added the answers. Let me know if that is the answer you are looking for or give an example of what you want your answer to look like.

Comment: Thank a lot @suecarmol, but it is not right answer. I want get some wantList in member (Not all), but your answer is showing all wantList.

Comment: Just updated the answer. I think this is the answer you are looking for! If so, please mark as answered.

Comment: Hi @suecarmol, i tested your answer. But it didn't show wantList with wantList.title : "Want 2.2 - HN". Maybe it was missing a little something. I almost have the answer for my question.

Comment: Unfortunately, $elemMatch only returns the first element, for your answer, you will have to do an aggregation. I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: Thanks a lot @suecarmol.